# use of & in POPUP "&Query" in vc++ code

Tags: visual-c++, popup

I have `POPUP "&Query"` and `POPUP "Main&tenance"` written in my code in vc++. What is the use of `&`? What effect does it have in the gui?

Comment: What you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you're referring to a menu resource file. The character after the ampersand (&) indicates the keyboard shortcut for the menu item. It's the one that gets an underline when the user presses <kbd>Alt</kbd>.